# Finding mean with least number of iterations

Tags: java, algorithm, math, statistics, performance

I have a list of measurements with the following properties:

1. The measurements are expensive. Fewer measurements -> better
2. They are all positive. In fact, there is a positive lower limit and I can't get any values below that. This lower limit is what I need to know with some confidence.
3. They will distribute around one or more median values
4. I know that there is another "better" median when I find an outlier which is smaller than `median - 2*variance` because the distance between the "best" median and the lower limit is always smaller than two times the width of the normal distribution

Goal: Find the best median with the least amount of iterations with a confidence of, say, 90%.

I'd prefer the smallest value but the smallest median is good enough.

What I'm looking for is a piece of code where I feed the measurements and which tells me the median and how confident it is that this median is the one I seek.

Background: I want to time Java methods. I could run the test for a couple of minutes to average outliers out but when looking at the data, it's pretty obvious for a human that the values quickly accumulate around the median value.

Unless the JIT kicks in and the median suddenly jumps. Eventually, you will end up with a curve that is very steep left of the smallest median (i.e. the variance on the left side of the median is low) and a long, soft slope on the right side with a bump where the pre-JIT median was.

[Sample test data (13KB)](http://www.pdark.de/7ac2ce265a6a19ff53cb8591536ce8c2eae8ea74/performance.zip)

`testConnect-count.csv` is a histogram of the values, `testConnect-history.csv` is the sequence of measurements. The goal is find an algorithm which returns the smaller median around `115000` by reading the smallest number of values from `testConnect-history.csv`

Comment: Consider posting it here: http://statistics.stackexchange.com

Comment: I can't provide any code but it seems that this could be classified as an n-armed (or multi-armed) bandit problem. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit "Wikipedia Entry")

Comment: @thekashyap -- the stats stackexchange really isn't good when you're looking for algorithms. i'd suggest cs instead.

Comment: Are you looking for something like the median? For the mean you just take the average, only one pass is needed.

Comment: In your data the median is 116000. What number are you looking for?

Comment: BTW: the variance is meaningful when you have a normal distribution. Latencies don't follow a normal distribution. Note: you usually don't care what the typical or best times are, you tend to look at the worst 1% or 0.1% or 0.01%. i.e. the percentiles.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: It's a multimodal distribution (see [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bimodal_distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/bimodal_distribution)). He's looking for the least-valued mode.

Comment: That will be close to the median, which is your best performance. Its your worst performance which you generally have a problem with.

Comment: The "background" implies that the values of measurements are not randomly selected according to a fixed distribution; rather, it implies that sequentially-adjacent measurements will tend to be closer together -- and, more specifically, that the first batch of measurements will cluster around a mode that you don't want. Without some way of quantifying this pattern, there is no way to compute a "confidence" in any real statistical sense.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: That's not true. In a multimodal distribution, the median will tend to be between the modes.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I have to admit that I understand what statistics is for but I don't understand the terms or the formulas and when to apply them. I will accept any answer this gives me the peak around 50000.

Comment: @ruakh: Bimodal distribution looks promising. What I see in reality is that the data points are all close to one peak and then, they suddenly jump. After that, they distribute all around a lower peak. That is why I came up with the idea of the `median-2*sigma` as a lower bound because the lower limit is within that range.

Comment: Your smallest value is 110,000. Where do you get 50,000 from?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Damn, I was looking at the wrong file. Okay. For the ZIP above, the lower median is between `115000` and `116000` and the higher one is around `171000`. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it common practice to look at percentiles for latency as they don't follow a normal distribution and its the longer latencies which will hurt you.

In your case you could use the 50th percentile and 90th percentile.

These are simple to calculate if you have a sorted collection

```
List<Long> times = ....
Collections.sort(times);
long median = times.get(times.size()/2);
long ninetyth = times.get(times.size()*9/10);
```

I use trove as this can be more efficient for timing sensitive tests. It uses primitive values instead of creating objects.

```
TLongArrayList times = 
times.sort();
long median = times.get(times.size()/2);
long ninetyth = times.get(times.size()*9/10);
long ninetynineth = times.get(times.size()*99/100);
```

In your case the median is 116000 and the 90%tile is 170000. The 99%tile is 255000

Comment: Sorry, that won't work because I don't have a list. I get the values in the order that you see `testConnect-history.csv`. I need an algorithm that can return `116000` after reading the file line by line and stopping way before end of file. Also, I'm looking for the lower bound of the runtime, the upper bound is useless because some other process can interrupt my measurements at any time for an unknown amount of time.

Comment: I could get that value by running the measurement for a couple of days but I look for a way to stop as soon as possible.

Comment: So you want the most optimistic estimate of latency. How is that useful?

Comment: My goal is to get a warning when the runtime of an important section of the code changes "too much" where "too much" depends on many factors -> must be configured per case. I can get the desired result by running the measurement for a couple of minutes but looking at the numbers as a human, I can get away with looking at about 2000 of the 16000 values to see the peak. How can a computer do the same?

Comment: I take the results, sort them and pick a small number of values like 50%, 90% and 99%.  Then I check they are within some range like `assertEquals(expected, percentile, range);` This ensures that 99% of the values are as expected.  With a longer test you might get reproduce-able 99.3%tile. (For that you need closer to 100,000 samples)

Comment: **You cannot take the results!** I want you to read the file **line by line** and tell me when to **stop reading.**

Comment: I don't know why you don't want to read the whole file as it not very large I assume (unless it contains *lots* of other data), but you can just stop when you get a stable value.  For 90% this might be after 1000 samples.

Comment: Because this file doesn't exist in the real world. I just created it so I don't have to send you a 500MB Java project. In the real world, you get each value individually and **each value is very expensive so it's of utmost importance that you read as few values as possible.**

Comment: Think of it this way: Each `readLine` takes 10 minutes. Please optimize.

Comment: In that case you have a real problem because there will always be a trade of between accuracy and the number of samples you take.  In Java you have a warmup so you may have to ignore the first 10,000 samples or more to get a repeatable number. Your timings suggest you are timing a few milli-seconds so if its taking more than this time to log/record you have a serious issue.

Comment: Well, if it was a simple problem, I wouldn't be asking :-) As you can see in my question, I'm aware of this tradeoff. But since I, as a human, can see the heap building, there should be a way to teach this to a computer.

Comment: You can take the 50%tile at any time, and for 90%tile you need a minimum of 10 samples. Everything after that is an improvement. You have to use your judgement as to when it a good time to stop. This depends on your application. IMHO, There is no generic answer to this question.

Comment: There is no way to find a "bump" in a list of values with a certain slope?

Comment: You can do that with five values by taking the median. To find two bumps, you need about seven values minimum. How accurate this is I wouldn't like to say.

Comment: In the sample data you gave, the second "mode" is apparent at point 1000, but is extremely rare before point 720. From point 7000 to 15000 the second mode rarely occurs. It is hard to say whether in a different run, you could get a run of 8000 values without the second mode, right from the start.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16694/discussion-between-aaron-digulla-and-peter-lawrey)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the actual question is: give me the average execution of a subprogram after it has been JIT-optimized.

The process is not stationary. The time for the JIT to kick in depends on the actual virtual machine implementation and the program under test. I believe You won't find a general-purpose-magic-bullet method.

You must experiment. I`d try throwing away a fixed number of measurements, make a fixed number of measurements, throw away outliers, take average of the rest.